# Phase release appstoreconnect iOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer-account

I have few queries if I choose phase release option on App Store Connect:

1. What happen if I pause the current release and submit the new version? Are remaining users which haven't received the current update due to the pause of the release will directly get new version update or current one?
2. if i remove the application from the sale, what will happen to old users which already received the update and what will happen of i resubmit the application?
3. Consider we pause the release on day 1(1% user targeted) and due to critical issue i have resubmitted the new version with phase release again so apple target same 1% or it will be random selection?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you start a new release, the selection of users starts from 1% again and the selection will be random. But if their account is not selected for the new update, they will get the latest version available (the paused one).
2. Users with the application downloaded will be able to use the last one published
3. Same as 1), the selection is random

Keep in mind that any user updating manually from the AppStore will get the latest version, staged rollout only works for automatic updates

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am un clear on this sentence "But if their account is not selected for the new update, they will get the latest version available (the paused one)."

Is that mean if version 2 got rollout to 1% and after that i paused it and release new version 2.1 and if user not selected for 2.1 version apple automatically install the version 2 if autoupdate on for that user. Really appreciate if you can guide me on this Thanks 